# Issues Running App on Shinyapps (Leaflet Map Mislabelled)

Tags: r, shiny

I am having what seems to be a very strange problem with my shiny app, and would definitely appreciate some help. The app is currently on shinyapps.io. You can see it here: https://esbriskin.shinyapps.io/Media_Freedoms/ 2

I am interested in visualizing trends pertaining to press freedoms around the world. I have created an interactive map using Shiny and Leaflet where countries are shaded based off of their press freedom score (darker, redder shades = higher press freedom scores which indicate lower press freedoms overall). When you hover over each country, the name and the score will appear as a label. You can adjust the scores by year by adjusting the orange knob on the bottom.

What's strange is that when I run the app locally on my computer, it works fine, but when I upload it to the server, certain countries are mislabeled and not colored correctly. Here is what it is supposed to look like (when run locally):

[App run locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w0Ec.png)

However, when it is on the shinyapps server for example, 'Canada' is labelled and colored as 'Cameroon,' 'China' is labelled and colored as 'Chile,' and a few other countries are mislabeled. I have tried troubleshooting multiple aspects - I tried using a world shapefile instead of the 'rworldmap' function, and I joined country data by ISO3 codes as opposed to country names to avoid potential confusion, all with the same result: it works perfectly fine locally but once it's on the shinyapps server, it mislabels these countries.

The code is below. I have also posted it on R-Studio Cloud, which you can access with this link: https://rstudio.cloud/project/194425

[The data used is available for download here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1naPVJ5su31YGx4jNIg7yH5RzEs3hywul/view)

```
# Load Libraries  

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(rAmCharts)
library(rsconnect)

pf <- read.csv("Index_Data_2000.csv", header = TRUE)

# Cleaning the data 

pfg <- pf[ -c(2:11) ]

pfg <- gather(pfg, measure, score, A.Legal:Status.16, factor_key = TRUE)

colnames(pfg)[1] = "country"

pfg$score <- as.numeric(pfg$score)

pfg <- pfg %>% arrange(country)

# Creating a 'year' Column

year <- data.frame(rep(seq(2001,2016, by = 1), 5))

colnames(year) <- "year"

year <- year %>% arrange(year)

y <- rep(as.vector(year), each = 197)

y <- data.frame(unlist(y, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE))

pfg <- cbind(pfg, y)

colnames(pfg)[4] = "year"

# Cleaning the 'measure' Column

measurenames <- c("Legal", "Political", "Economic", "Total_Score", "Status")

measurenames <- data.frame(rep(measurenames, 3152))

pfg <- cbind(pfg, measurenames)

pfg$measure <- NULL

colnames(pfg)[4] = "measure"

# Adding ISO3 codes to country data to use as join key


ISO3 <- c("AFG",
          "ALB",
          "DZA",
          "AGO",
          "ATG",
          "ARG",
          "ARM",
          "AUS",
          "AUT",
          "AZE",
          "BHS",
          "BHR",
          "BGD",
          "BRB",
          "BlR",
          "BEL",
          "BLZ",
          "BEN",
          "BTN",
          "BOL",
          "BIH",
          "BWA",
          "BRA",
          "BRN",
          "BGR",
          "BFA",
          "BDI",
          "KHM",
          "CMR",
          "CAN",
          "CPV",
          "CAF",
          "TCD",
          "CHL",
          "CHN",
          "COL",
          "COM",
          "COG",
          "COD",
          "CRI",
          "CIV",
          "HRV",
          "CUB",
          "CYP",
          "CZE",
          "DNK",
          "DJI",
          "DMA",
          "DOM",
          "ECU",
          "EGY",
          "SLV",
          "GNQ",
          "ERI",
          "EST",
          "ETH",
          "FJI",
          "FIN",
          "FRA",
          "GAB",
          "GEO",
          "DEU",
          "GHA",
          "GRC",
          "GRD",
          "GTM",
          "GIN",
          "GNB",
          "GUY",
          "HTI",
          "HND",
          "HKG",
          "HUN",
          "ISL",
          "IND",
          "IDN",
          "IRN",
          "IRQ",
          "IRL",
          "ISR",
          "PSE",
          "ITA",
          "JAM",
          "JPN",
          "JOR",
          "KAZ",
          "KEN",
          "KIR",
          "KOS",
          "KWT",
          "KGZ",
          "LAO",
          "LVA",
          "LBN",
          "LSO",
          "LBR",
          "LBY",
          "LIE",
          "LTU",
          "LUX",
          "MKD",
          "MDG",
          "MWI",
          "MYS",
          "MDV",
          "MLI",
          "MLT",
          "MHL",
          "MRT",
          "MUS",
          "MEX",
          "FSM",
          "MDA",
          "MCO",
          "MNG",
          "MNE",
          "MAR",
          "MOZ",
          "MMR",
          "NAM",
          "NRU",
          "NPL",
          "NLD",
          "NZL",
          "NIC",
          "NER",
          "NGA",
          "PRK",
          "NOR",
          "OMN",
          "PAK",
          "PLW",
          "PAN",
          "PNG",
          "PRY",
          "PER",
          "PHL",
          "POL",
          "PRT",
          "QAT",
          "ROU",
          "RUS",
          "RWA",
          "KNA",
          "LCA",
          "VCT",
          "WSM",
          "SMR",
          "STP",
          "SAU",
          "SEN",
          "SRB",
          "SYC",
          "SLE",
          "SGP",
          "SVK",
          "SVN",
          "SLB",
          "SOM",
          "ZAF",
          "KOR",
          "SON",
          "ESP",
          "LKA",
          "SON",
          "SUR",
          "SWZ",
          "SWE",
          "CHE",
          "SYR",
          "TWN",
          "TJK",
          "TZA",
          "THA",
          "GMB",
          "TLS",
          "TGO",
          "TON",
          "TTO",
          "TUN",
          "TUR",
          "TKM",
          "TUV",
          "UGA",
          "UKR",
          "ARE",
          "GBR",
          "USA",
          "URY",
          "UZB",
          "VUT",
          "VEN",
          "VNM",
          "PSE",
          "YEM",
          "ZMB",
          "ZWE") 

i <- rep(ISO3, each = 80)

pfg <- cbind(pfg, i)

pfg <- pfg %>% rename(ISO3 = i)

# Creating data used to rank country press freedoms

pfg.rankings <- pfg %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    filter(measure %in% "Total_Score") %>%
    arrange(year, score) %>%
    mutate(ranking = row_number())

# Creating the Map Data
pfgts <- pfg %>% filter(measure %in% "Total_Score")
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = pfgts$score, bins = 5)


# Creates data for yearly press freedom trends with rAMCharts

pfgam <- spread(pfg, measure, score)
pfgam$year <- as.POSIXct(paste(pfgam$year), format = "%Y")

# Interactive Data Table

pfgt <- pfg %>%
    group_by(year, country, measure) 

pfgtable <- spread(pfgt, measure, score)
pfgtable$Status <- NULL

# Dashboard

header <- dashboardHeader(title = span(tagList(icon("calendar"), "Press Freedom Index")))

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("World Map", tabName = "map"),
        menuItem("Historical Score Data by Year", tabName = "score"),
        menuItem("Country Rankings", tabName = "rankings"),
        menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "table")
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "map",
                leafletOutput("worldmap", height = 1000),
                absolutePanel(top = 490, right = '73%', height = 100, width =  100, fixed = FALSE,
                              knobInput(
                                  inputId = "year",
                                  label = "",
                                  value = 2016,
                                  min = 2001,
                                  max = 2016,
                                  displayPrevious = FALSE, 
                                  lineCap = "round",
                                  fgColor = "#F37C05",
                                  bgColor = "FFFFFF",
                                  inputColor = "#F37C05",
                                  width = 100,
                                  height = 100,
                                  immediate = FALSE
                              ))
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "score",
                fluidRow(
                    box(title = "Press Freedom Index", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning", width = 12,
                        h1('Looking at Year By Year Trends in Press Freedoms'),
                        p('The data used for this application is provided by Freedom House
                    and can be accessed with this link:'),
                        strong('https://freedomhouse.org/report-types/freedom-press'),

                        p('Scores on press freedoms have been measured and determined through the context of three different environments:'),

                        tags$li('Legal (range of 1 - 30)'),
                        tags$li('Political (range of 1 - 40)'),
                        tags$li('Environment (range of 1 - 30)'),

                        p('Countries with a higher score indicate lower amounts of freedom. Total scores
are therefore assigned out of 100 - countries with greater amounts of press freedoms have lower scores and countries 
with lesser amounts of press freedoms have higher scores.'),
                        amChartsOutput("score", height = 520),
                        absolutePanel(top = 80, right = 70, fixed = FALSE,
                                      selectInput("country", "Select a Country", choices = levels(pfgam$country), width = 200))
                    )
                )
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "rankings",
                fluidRow(
                    box(title = "Country Rankings", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning", width = 12,
                        h1('Press Freedoms Relative to Other Countries'),
                        p('Here you can look at how other press freedoms of countries compare with eachother by rank.
                    Adjust the circular knob to select the year, and select adjust the slider range to see a 
                    rank range (For example, select 1 and 10 to see the top 10 countries for press freedoms)'),
                        sliderInput("range", "Select Ranking Range", min = 1, max = 197, value = c(1, 10), step = 1, dragRange = TRUE),

                        amChartsOutput("rank"),
                        absolutePanel(top = 300, right = 70, fixed = FALSE,
                                      knobInput("rankyear", "", min = 2001, max = 2016, value = 2016,
                                                displayPrevious = FALSE, 
                                                lineCap = "round",
                                                fgColor = "#F37C05",
                                                bgColor = "FFFFFF",
                                                inputColor = "#F37C05",
                                                width = 100,
                                                height = 100,
                                                immediate = FALSE)
                        )

                    )
                )),
        tabItem(tabName = "table",
                fluidRow(
                    box(title = "Country Data", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning", width = 12,
                        h1('Press Freedom Data'),
                        p('Here you can look through country data manually. Use the search bar to filter data.'),
                        DTOutput('table'))
                )
        )
    )
)

# Define UI for application
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "yellow")

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    pfgam_re <- reactive({
        pfgam %>% filter(country %in% input$country)
    })

    pfg.rankings_re <- reactive({
        pfg.rankings %>%
            filter(year %in% input$rankyear) %>%
            slice(input$range[1]:input$range[2])
    })

    output$table <- renderDT({
        pfgtable
    })

    output$rank <- renderAmCharts({
        amBarplot(x = ("country"), y = "score", data = pfg.rankings_re(), horiz = TRUE, zoom = TRUE)
    })

    output$score <- renderAmCharts({
        amTimeSeries(pfgam_re(), 'year', c('Political', 'Economic', 'Legal', 'Total_Score'),
                     scrollbar = TRUE, main = paste("Yearly Press Freedom Scores In ", input$country))
    })

    selected <- reactive({
        pfgts <- pfgts %>% filter(year %in% input$year)
    })

    output$worldmap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 2)) %>%
            addMiniMap()

    })

    observe({
        if(!is.null(input$year)){
            map <- joinCountryData2Map(selected(), joinCode = "ISO3",
                                       nameJoinColumn = "ISO3")
            leafletProxy("worldmap", data = map) %>%
                addTiles() %>% 
                clearShapes() %>% 
                addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(map$score),
                            weight = 2,
                            opacity = 1,
                            color = "white",
                            dashArray = "3",
                            fillOpacity = 0.7,
                            highlight = highlightOptions(
                                weight = 5,
                                color = "white",
                                dashArray = "3",
                                fillOpacity = .8,
                                bringToFront = TRUE),
                            label = ~paste(as.character(map$country),
                                           "Total Index Score: ", as.character(map$score)))
        }})


}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Again, I am definitely stumped and would really appreciate any help on this!